# How to make CSS counter to count just headings, not pages

Tags: css, counter, css-counter

I have a problem with a counter of headings in a pdf document. Counter for headings should be correspondent to their TOC (Table of contents), but for some reason, it counts pages, especially if there are multiple pages.

Below is an example of my current code:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: h1count 0 h2count 0 h3count 0;
} 

.pagetitle {
  page-break-before: always;
}


h1 {
  counter-reset: h2count;
  counter-increment: h1count;
}


h2 {
  counter-reset: h3count;
  counter-increment: h2count;
}


h3 {
  counter-increment: h3count;
}


h1:before {
  content: counter(h1count)". ";
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(h1count)"." counter(h2count)" ";
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(h1count)"." counter(h2count)"." counter(h3count)" ";
}
```

[EXPECTED RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZO6c.png)

[WHAT I ACTUALLY GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUTHX.png)

Comment: It seems to work if the HTML is correct. Could you add your HTML - the HTML that gives you that output you have shown.

Comment: @AHaworth I don't have HTML for this, because this is a PDF export for documentation. I can just generate CSS changes.